# jQuery .clone() of a <select>: change the selected option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When loading a list of records from my database to display them in a html grid, I need to put a few `<select>` in a couple columns.

In my javascript, I do an ajax call to receive my data in json format and push my results in an array. In my display function, I then loop on the array and construct my table's multiple `<tr>` to a string and then push that html string in the `<tbody>` of my table:

```
if (buildingList) {

    buildingList.forEach(function(element) {
        buildingListHTML += "<tr>";
            buildingListHTML += "<td>" + element.nID + "</td>";
            buildingListHTML += "<td>" + element.cTaskNumber + "</td>";
            buildingListHTML += "<td>" + element.nProductTypeID + "</td>";
            buildingListHTML += "<td>" + element.nQty + "</td>";
            buildingListHTML += "<td>" + element.dRequired + "</td>";
            buildingListHTML += "<td><input type='checkbox'" + ((element.bCompleted == 0) ? "" : "checked") + " disabled></td>";
        buildingListHTML += "</tr>";
    });
}
$("#workOrderBuildingListBody").html(buildingListHTML);
```

That part works well. But now, for my column nProductTypeID, I want to display a `<select>` with my list of product types, and automatically select the right one from the list, according to the ID I have.

Basically, what I've done so far is create a `<select>` in a hidden `<div>` in my php file:

```
<div id="WOSkuSelectTemplate" style="display: none;">
    <select class="WOSkuSelect">
        <?php Common::generateProdTypesOptions($db); ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then, instead of just doing `"<td>" + element.nProductTypeID + "</td>"`, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if(actionsList) { //if there are actions entries
    actionsList.forEach(function(element) {
        var WOSkuSelectTemplate = $("#WOSkuSelectTemplate").clone().html();
        $(WOSkuSelectTemplate).val(element.nProductTypeID);
        alert(WOSkuSelectTemplate);

        actionsListHTML += "<tr>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.nID + "</td>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.cTaskNumber + "</td>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td>" + WOSkuSelectTemplate + "</td>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.nQty + "</td>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.nActionTypeID + "</td>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.cFrom + "</td>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.cTo + "</td>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.dRequired + "</td>";
            actionsListHTML += "<td><input type='checkbox'" + ((element.bCompleted == 0) ? "" : "checked") + " disabled></td>";
        actionsListHTML += "</tr>";

    });
}
$("#workOrderActionsListBody").html(actionsListHTML);
```

I've tried multiple ways of doing it it, but nothing works. If I clone the `<select>` itself, when I try to concatenate my strings, when I do `"<td>" + WOSkuSelectTemplate + "<td>"`, it just displays something like `[object: object]`. if I do `+ WOSkuSelectTemplate.html() +`, I get only the options without the select, which is why I am instead cloning a `<div>`and get the .html(), which gives me the `<select>` itself with the options.

But whatever I try, I cannot seem to make the `$(WOSkuSelectTemplate).val(element.nProductTypeID);` part to work... All my `<select>`are there with the options in them, but they don't select the proper row. The comboboxes themselves have the right values, I can even set them from the console. but I can't get my javascript to do it for me.

The only option I see if to get the string like I do, and do a replace of `'selected=""'` for `'selected="' + element.nProductTypeID + '"'` but I really don't find that clean...

Is there any other way to achieve this?

English is not my primary language, sorry if anything is unclear.

Thank you.

Comment: it should be `WOSkuSelectTemplate.val(element.nProductTypeID);` instead of `$(WOSkuSelectTemplate).val(element.nProductTypeID);`

Comment: you have already created the jQuery Object of `#WOSkuSelectTemplate`

Comment: ^ that, because you already are using a jQuery selector in that variable

Comment: That doesn't work because my WOSkuSelectTemplate variable is the div and not the select. If I make WOSkuSelectTemplate the select itself, then when I display it, I get only [object Object] and if I display it's .html(), I get only the options.

Comment: this is why WOSkuSelectTemplate is the div, so that when I do the .html(), I get the select and the options. But then setting the .val() doesn't work as it's trying to assign the value to the div. I need to be able to assign the .val() of the select that is IN WOSkuSelectTemplate.

Comment: or make WOSkuSelectTemplate the div itself but be able to return the full HTML and not just whats inside of it (not the just innerHTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
WOSkuSelectTemplate.find('select').find("option[value = '" + element.nProductTypeID + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's "dirty" but you can do this:

```js
// [test code]
var actionsList = [{
    nProductTypeID: 2, 
    nID: 1, 
    cTaskNumber: 3, 
    nQty: 10,
    nActionTypeID: 75,
    cFrom: "John", 
    cTo: "Doe", 
    dRequired: "true", 
    bCompleted: 0
}];

// [/test code]

$(document).ready(function() {

// other code...
    var actionsListHTML = "";

    if(actionsList) { //if there are actions entries
        actionsList.forEach(function(element) {
            var clonedDivWithSelect = $("#WOSkuSelectTemplate").clone();
            clonedDivWithSelect.find("option[value=\"" + element.nProductTypeID + "\"]").attr("selected", "selected");
            
            actionsListHTML += "<tr>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.nID + "</td>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.cTaskNumber + "</td>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td>" + clonedDivWithSelect.html() + "</td>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.nQty + "</td>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.nActionTypeID + "</td>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.cFrom + "</td>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.cTo + "</td>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td>" + element.dRequired + "</td>";
                actionsListHTML += "<td><input type='checkbox'" + ((element.bCompleted == 0) ? "" : "checked") + " disabled></td>";
            actionsListHTML += "</tr>";
            
        });
    }
    $("#workOrderActionsListBody").html(actionsListHTML);
    
    // other code...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="WOSkuSelectTemplate" style="display: none;">
    <select class="WOSkuSelect">
        <option value="0">Test option 0</option>
        <option value="1">Test option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody id="workOrderActionsListBody">
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S. Yeah Agam Banga beat me on time about the selection part.

Comment: Thank you! I took Agam's answer but thanks for your time!